# Get jQuery object from HTML Element

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

this is my code:

```
<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showObj(this);"></a></td></tr>

function showObj(object){
    var row = $(object).closest('tr');
}
```

and it show this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method
>   'closest'

How can I change the element to jQuery object or how to point to table row in which was this anchor clicked?

Thank you.

Comment: I forgot that jQuery library is included of course :)

Comment: your code works if you use jquery version >= 1.3 which i hope it's the case

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/kP6jB/  according to roasted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way more clean approach would be to give your table an ID and get the rows using a jQuery selector like this:

```
$("#table tr td a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

And your HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr><td><a>Link 1</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a>Link 2</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Edit:
You could also use jQuery's parents() instead of closest(), like:

```
var row = $(object).closest('tr');
```

instead of

```
var row = $(object).parents('tr');
```

Comment: I just want to get another solution. I know about binding event like .click, .bind, .on, .delegate etc... but I need to know how to change the HTML element to jQuery. This is the main question.

Comment: Then see Roasted's answer and Dado Jerry's fiddle. What is your jQuery version?

Comment: You could also try jQuery's parents() instead of closest(), like:
var row = $(object).parents('tr');

Comment: yes I was using old jQuery version which doesn't know closest() function. parents() are good now.

Comment: I added it to my original answer, could you mark it as the answer?